# Centering some floated div without width

Tags: html

I have some floated divs where I can't use display: inline-block because some of those divs are jqxSwitchButtons and using that inline-block would mess everything around those buttons.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Luigino/Ps3zE/) is a JSFiddle example where I commented some lines that are jqxSwitchButtons and I'd like to center in the middle those divs.

Code from JSFiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
    <center>
            <table style="padding:1px;margin:1px;color:#00417B;font-size:12px;border:2px solid #525252;border-collapse: collapse;background-color:white;width: 100%;" border=1>
            <tr><td>
            <div style="display: block; align:center; width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-right: auto; padding-left: auto; text-align: center;">

            <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px; font-weight: bold; ">Element 1</div>
            <div><div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px; border: 0.1em solid green; width: 10px; height: 21px;"><div id="element_1" style="float: left;"></div></div></div> <!-- jqxSwitchButton -->

            <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px; font-weight: bold; ">Element 2</div>
            <div><div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px; border: 0.1em solid green; width: 10px; height: 21px;"><div id="element_2" style="float: left;"></div></div></div> <!-- jqxSwitchButton -->

            <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px; font-weight: bold; ">Element 3</div>
            <div><div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px; border: 0.1em solid green; width: 10px; height: 21px;"><div id="element_3" style="float: left;"></div></div></div> <!-- jqxSwitchButton -->

            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 1px">|</div>

            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 2px"><input type="button" id="btnCompute" value="Compute" onClick="Compute()" style="margin-top: 4px"></div>

            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 1px">|</div>

            <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 2px; font-weight: bold; ">Auto-compute</div>
            <div><div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px; border: 0.1em solid green; width: 10px; height: 21px;"><div id="recompute" style="float: left;"></div></div></div> <!-- jqxSwitchButton -->

            <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 2px; font-weight: bold; "><input type="checkbox" name="chkAutoRecompute" id="chkAutoRecompute" value="0" style="display: none" ></div>

            </div>

            </td></tr>

            </table>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: first of all validate your html code ( http://validator.w3.org/check might help you). Then try using a div inside the <td> with properties display: block; margin:0px auto; float: none; (vertical margin how many pixels you like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Cyborgx37 and mitchelltrout! At the end, I solved using a fixed width on container div set properly depending on media queries so for different resolutions I set a different width so I could have all aligned in one row. Thanks again to all for the help though. Ciao, Luigino

Answer (score 0):

the proper way of centering things with CSS is to margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;. but since your already changing the margins for those divs i would suggest using the depreciated `<center></center>` HTML tag. it will still work in modern browsers even though it was depreciated years ago. im not sure if any of the browsers have plans to remove the center tag in future versions.

Comment: And using a deprecated HTML element is, by definition, not recommended. Even if it "works", it may not work the same way in all browsers (mobile, etc) and may lose support at any arbitrary time in the future. An outer wrapper div would be preferable.

Comment: Hello Cyborgx37 and mitchelltrout, I have already used an outer div as you can see that div with all those margin-left and margin-right set to auto, plus I put also a <center> inside the <td> that contains all those divs, styled also the <td> itself applying margin-right/left auto, text-align and align as center but nothing... any other tricks I can try?... thanks again